# Spark Strucutured Streaming Window on non-timestamp column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, aggregate-functions, spark-structured-streaming

I am getting a data stream of the form:

```
+--+---------+---+----+
|id|timestamp|val|xxx |
+--+---------+---+----+
|1 |12:15:25 | 50| 1  |
|2 |12:15:25 | 30| 1  |
|3 |12:15:26 | 30| 2  |
|4 |12:15:27 | 50| 2  |
|5 |12:15:27 | 30| 3  |
|6 |12:15:27 | 60| 4  |
|7 |12:15:28 | 50| 5  |
|8 |12:15:30 | 60| 5  |
|9 |12:15:31 | 30| 6  |
|. |...      |...|... |
```

I am interested in applying window operation to the `xxx` column just like the window operation over timestamp is available in Spark Streaming with some window size and sliding step.

Let in the `groupBy` with window function below, `lines` represent a streaming dataframe with window size: 2 and sliding step: 1.

```
val c_windowed_count = lines.groupBy(
  window($"xxx", "2", "1"), $"val").count().orderBy("xxx")
```

So, the output should be as follows:

```
+------+---+-----+
|window|val|count|
+------+---+-----+
|[1, 3]|50 |  2  |
|[1, 3]|30 |  2  |
|[2, 4]|30 |  2  |
|[2, 4]|50 |  1  |
|[3, 5]|30 |  1  |
|[3, 5]|60 |  1  |
|[4, 6]|60 |  2  |
|[4, 6]|50 |  1  |
|...   |.. | ..  |
```

I tried using `partitionBy` but it is not supported in Spark Structured Streaming.

I am using Spark Structured Streaming 2.3.1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's currently not possible to use windows on non-timestamp columns in this way using Spark Structured Streaming. However, what you can do is **convert the `xxx` column to a timestamp column**, do the `groupBy` and `count`, and then transform back.

`from_unixtime` can be used to convert the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 to a timestamp. Use the `xxx` column as seconds and it's possible to create a *fake timestamp* to use in a window:

```
lines.groupBy(window(from_unixtime($"xxx"), "2 seconds", "1 seconds"), $"val").count()
  .withColumn("window", struct(unix_timestamp($"window.start"), unix_timestamp($"window.end")).as("window"))
  .filter($"window.col1" =!= 0)
  .orderBy($"window.col1")
```

Above, the grouping is done on the converted timestamp and the next row will convert it back to it's original number. The filter is done since the first two rows will be one a window `[0,2]` (i.e. only on the rows with `xxx` equals `1`) but can be skipped.

Resulting output of the above input:

```
+------+---+-----+
|window|val|count|
+------+---+-----+
| [1,3]| 50|    2|
| [1,3]| 30|    2|
| [2,4]| 30|    2|
| [2,4]| 50|    1|
| [3,5]| 30|    1|
| [3,5]| 60|    1|
| [4,6]| 60|    2|
| [4,6]| 50|    1|
| [5,7]| 30|    1|
| [5,7]| 60|    1|
| [5,7]| 50|    1|
| [6,8]| 30|    1|
+------+---+-----+
```

Comment: Many thanks Shaido! Great logic and perfect answer :)

Comment: @shaikh: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

New in spark 2.2 is  [arbitrary-stateful-operations](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#arbitrary-stateful-operations)

A use case is managing user sessions, a 'user window'

[scroll half way down this page to see an example](https://databricks.com/blog/2017/10/17/arbitrary-stateful-processing-in-apache-sparks-structured-streaming.html)

If Shaido's clever solution is working for you then I suggest stay with that.  For more complex requirements arbitrary-stateful-operations looks like the way to go.